# Write image metadata in ,net mvc causes change in file size

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, bitmap

I try to modify the metadata information for few uploaded image files in an mvc3 application and i found that for tiff images the size of file is getting increased by 90% [ actual file size is 4 MB , then after updating metadata i found size as 9 MB ] And it sees to be the issue is only for tiff images . I tried the other image formats like png , jpeg , bmp etc and no issue in sizing after updating metadata . 
Here is the code i used to save metadata [ modify metadata]

```
        BitmapDecoder decoder = null;
    BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = null;
    BitmapMetadata metadata = null;
    BitmapEncoder encoder = null;            
    using (Stream bitmapStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
    {
        //This combination seems to work. The BitmapCacheOption.onload argument to BitmapDecoder.Create() is the only combination that seems to work. Otherwise, we get a file in use if we try to accessit from another thread.                    
        decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(bitmapStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        bitmapStream.Close();
    }
    if (decoder != null)
    {
        bitmapFrame = decoder.Frames[0];
        if (bitmapFrame != null && bitmapFrame.Metadata != null)
        {
            // clone the image file's metadata                        
            metadata = (BitmapMetadata)bitmapFrame.Metadata.Clone();
            metadata.Title = "";//value here
            metadata.Comment = "";//value here
            metadata.Author = "";//value here
            metadata.Copyright = "";//value here
            metadata.Keywords = "";//value here 
            switch (mymethods.getMimeType(filename))
            {
                case "image/jpeg":
                    encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                    break;
                case "image/png":
                    encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                    break;
                case "image/tiff":
                    encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
                    break;
                case "image/gif":
                    encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
                    break;
                case "image/bmp":
                    encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                    break;
                default:
                    encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                    break;
            }
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapFrame, bitmapFrame.Thumbnail, metadata, bitmapFrame.ColorContexts));
            using (Stream outStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
            {
                encoder.Save(outStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code snippet helps me to modify the metadata , but only issue is re-sizing of saved image  of few formats

Comment: Try playing around with the encoder.Compression property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapencoder.compression(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No luck still getting the double size after saving

Comment: The last bit of your code where you save the image, is it simply adding the updated metadata image to the existing image (hence double size)? Open image and check page count. Also DPI increase may be the problem.

Comment: Can you help to optimize this ?

Comment: If what I mentioned above is actually occurring (I think it is), do a Google on 'overwite frames in tiff c#'. I have never done this before, but the concept seems simple enough. Or you could simply create a new tiff, then upon saving delete the original and update the new tiff name to match.